# Quarkus application deployment failing in openshift?

Tags: openshift, quarkus

we are using
quarkus.application.timestamp=${maven.build.timestamp} in properties file and trying to access the  timestamp in java class by:
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.timestamp")
String buildTime;

But the deployment is failing due to this

Comment: What is failure? Have you enabled maven resource filtering?

Comment: yes ,enabled the maven resource  filtering ..it is working locally. but the gitlab pipeline till build is success but deployment is failed with error "cannot create resource"

Comment: Please add the entire log of the problem to the description